# Alternative localization with extension methods

Tags: c#, resources, localization, extension-methods

I am about to start a localization project for my employer. It concerns a pre-existing project with many windows forms and an established code base, programmed in C# and ASP.NET. I have done research into how to localize an application in visual studio and found resources.

While these are an adequate solution to the problem, I am not entirely happy with the down sides of using resources. This is to say, it has a rather large footprint, requiring changes in each of the form files. Furthermore, the resource files are only editable from within Visual Studio. I would prefer enabling external translators without programming knowledge to do the translation.

So I came up with an alternative solution:

Build a static localization utility class with an extension method on String:

```
public static String Localize(this String s)
```

The utility class loads localization strings from file on startup. When the program needs a string somewhere, it is called as

```
"foo".Localize();
```

And the program would use the string itself as the key in the table to find the translation.
It seems a safe and effective solution, and I'm happy with the small footprint that it leaves on the existing codebase.

Basically I want to ask:

- Are there downsides to my solution that I've missed?
- Which file formats for the localization data should I look into (I've already encountered the .po file format)?
- Is it a good enough reason to deviate from the resource files solution?

Any advice and/or considerations you may have will be appreciated.

Comment: The impact on the existing codebase will be the same in my opinion. You have to add the method to all of the current literals. Are you going to use a text "Select one of the three options Banana, Kiwi or Orange" as a key ? Sounds tricky. I wouldn't deviate from the perfectly sane default solution. You can always redeploy the application if a different language is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel that MS invented long ago. You can use plenty of tools available for resources or even write your own Resources provider.

Some tools available: [What tools are available for adding Localization to an ASP.NET project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893786/what-tools-are-available-for-adding-localization-to-an-asp-net-project)

If you want to use a database for translators: [Data Driven Resource provider from Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/695968.aspx)

Comment: There was some very useful info there, especially the first link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there downsides to my solution that I've missed?

I can point out some, what about the texts in the aspx files. Are you going to make your extension method available to them as well? That would be tough I guess.

e.g. `<asp:Label Text="Title">` - how are you going to translate that?

Further, some of your claims are not entirely true.

> the resource files are only editable from within Visual Studio

They are xml files , so you can use any editor to edit them or write a custom utility to do that.

Comment: Actually, this would be a problem in forms designer generated files as well. I was thinking I would run a recursive function on master control, that would iterate through all of the controls and localize their Text property.

Comment: Your point about resources as xml file is technically true. But the xml is not very readable at all, and writing a custom utility for them is not exactly desirable :)

Answer (score 0):

> Are there downsides to my solution that I've missed?

The standard resource files go beyond changing the text.

You might need to resize certain elements to fit the new text (if you don't use the existing layout management mechanism). And for some languages you will need to change the fonts/fonts sizes (think Chinese, Japanese, Korean) or alignment (think right-to-left languages like Arabic and Hebrew).

Also, translating standard files means that using an editor that is aware of the format one can see the dialog "as is", so it gives more context than stand-alone strings, which results in better translation quality.