# .NET localization tools

Tags: .net, localization, resx

Are there any tools, that ease work with localization in .NET? I mean work with resx files in VS is done pretty ugly from a developer point of view. For example, if I need to add a string to resources, I have to manually add it to all resource files with different cultures. And I do not know of any tools, that can tell me if there are strings missing in a resource file of particular cultures, and so on.

Comment: +1 Oh I can feel your pain!

Comment: @LexLi thanks, but "Extract to resource" is the feature of Resharper which I use all the time, but that is not enough. And second does not seems to work in VS 2010 (judging from comments on site and last update in 2007). More then that - ResEx website is not working =).

Comment: ResEx is now open source and hosted on CodePlex, http://resex.codeplex.com/ I will later update my post to reflect this change.

Comment: @LexLi and still last activity 2008 - 5 years from now...

Comment: To view an open source project, you should learn to go to its source code section, http://resex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets, which was last updated in 2012. Some project owners only publish a release when it is very stable, and that might take a very long time. For myself, the 2008 release is already very useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools are available for adding Localization to an ASP.NET project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893786/what-tools-are-available-for-adding-localization-to-an-asp-net-project)

Comment: As of today, Resharper provides a Localization Manager, https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/12/09/localization-becomes-easier-localization-manager-resharper-2019-3/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just found simple VS addon with what I was looking for!
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68
And it is free! ResXManager!

Comment: Just what I also needed.

Comment: Yeah this looks great. And there are more very similar extensions available in VS gallery.

Comment: Try [LSACreator](http://www.tbs-apps.com/lsacreator), it's a localization tool which requires only .dll/.exe files. No need to work with resources and it separates source code from language project.

Comment: @TomaszMalik is there anything similar to LSACreator that supports .NET Core 3.0 and above?

Comment: @Suren I don't know any other tool that works with dlls. I think LSACreator will support .NET Core in next few weeks. Write on support, you should get a replay very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried [crowdin.com](https://crowdin.com/) and it worked fairly well. It's a free online too.

- Nice, quick support.
- It's easy to edit resx files.
- Also supports a wide range of other resource files.
- It's easy to invite volonteers to help you translate the project if desired.

Comment: That's a nice service, thanks! But I need tools that work on my computer with my .NET solutions, preferrably inside Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I sell a professional localization tool for Visual Studio developers and their translators. It does specifically what you're asking but I stand to profit from it so I don't want to overtly promote it here (to conform with the site's rules). See my profile for the link address.

Answer (score 0):

Google for .NET Localization and you will find plenty of 3rd party tools.

I suggest looking into ResGen.exe, which comes with Visual Studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.80).aspx

Another suggestion:
Create an Excel file with your resources, and using formulas, construct final output to be placed in txt file.

Afterwards, just use ResGen to create the resx files.

On a related note:
Always use resx files when creating an app. You shall reap the benefits later when someone asks you: "Can this app be localized into Yiddish?". Hopefully you won't answer: Oy Vey. :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is what I want to be more comfortable. Not command-line interface of resgen, not manually checked Excel file, etc...

Comment: Then i guess you are out of luck, then my friend. :)

Comment: Not sure, I've found what I was looking for. Please read my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

ResGen comes with Visual Studio.  It is a basic editor that shows what files need to change when localizing .net. I would not recommend building a localization process around it.

Quality tools dedicated to the task will give you much better support.  they promote best practise and have connections to industry standard translation memory, terminology, etc.  These are important concepts for localization.

The better ones can be automated so that your language assemblies are generated immediately following new builds in the source language.

Google .net software localization for good solutions.

Comment: I've googled, and found nothing useful. I am not trying to find a way around ResGen. I am trying to find _comfortable_ tools which would work in VS with resx files, which then will be compiled by ResGen. Have you tried to work with a solutions localized to several languages? If yes, then you should know how it is annoying to add same named string to several resx files. Then you probably know how to find out that some strings are missing in some languages, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing the .resx files by hand, you could put all your translations key-value pairs in a spreadsheet and generate the source files from there.

That's how I've solved it in my project. I've created an Excel spreadsheet with VBA macro that generates the .resx files. Managing a spreadsheet is much easier. You can just insert or remove rows, spot and fill in missing values, and generate the sourcefiles again.

You can download my example here (also works for xcode or eclipse btw):
http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/multilanguage.zip

Comment: And again this supposed manual work with resources at generation stage and later when adding more text to resources...